# Undefined subroutine &main::add called at ex1.pl line 4

Tags: perl, module

I have a perl Module

MyMathLib.pm

```
package MyMathLib;
require Exporter;

@ISA = qw/EXPORTER/;

@EXPORT = qw/add/;

sub add
{
  $_[0] + $_[1];
}

1;
```

Ex1.pl

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#
use MyMathLib;
print add(1,2);
```

I am getting the below error:

> Undefined subroutine &main::add called at ex1.pl line 4.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Exporter not an EXPORTER.

If you include

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

in your scripts you'll activate [more checks](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) that would have shown you a clue to the problem:

```
Can't locate package EXPORTER for @MyMathLib::ISA at Ex1.pl line 5.
Undefined subroutine &main::add called at Ex1.pl line 6.
```

Comment: for a long time, it has been recommended to just use Exporter's import method, not subclass it.   replace the require and @ISA= with just `use Exporter 'import';`